# Multithreading in Java and thread assignment dynamically with increasing db row count

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an unusual requirement where if the db row count increases, I need to add new thread in an agile fashion and run a test for that while other threads are running the same test with (different data sets). Users add data rows into db at different time points. So, when a new row added, the thread count should increase and start it while other threads are continuing to work.

my current code doesn't work because the thread spawning occurs once and if there is one row in db table, it starts the thread, but the execution sequence is not assigning the next thread if a new db table row is added.  How best can I approach this problem? I looked and researched and tried but nothing works. I am hoping someone could help with implementation methodology.

Until es.submit finishes the next item in the list is not getting assigned in the for loop. Do I need to look at this completely differently?

Here is the code:

```
List<Trader> myList = SQLConnector.getListInfo();
List<List<Parts>> partitions = chopped(traderList, myList.size());
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(myList.size());

Collection<Future<?>> futures = new LinkedList<Future<?>>();

for (List<Parts> dateList : partitions) {
    MyCode tmpCommand = new MyCode(driver, "UA");
    tmpCommand.setTest(dateList);
    futures.add(es.submit(tmpCommand));
  }
}
```

Comment: do the tests run forever? If yes, you probably don't want a pool of threads since pools imply take/give-back - you just want to create a new Thread every time you detect a new row has been added (athough your code snippet provides no insight how you plan on detecting a new row has been added)

Comment: Thanks Jamey, Will assigning threads not through a pool but independently will have the threads run independently and the parent loop runs independently at the same time? Will that work? I though once the thread is started that will be child and the parent wont execute assigning the new threads for new data rows in db until that initial child thread is finished, creating essentially the same problem, wont it?

Comment: it's too hard to figure out what you're doing since you're not demonstrating how you detect a new row is added to the DB, and you didn't answer the "do the tests run forever" question (it doesn't seem like they should).  It does seem like you're design is fundamentally wrong though

Comment: Tests run for a set period of time, let us say for 2 hrs. And the SQLConnector.getListInfo(); gets my db rows.  Here is the code for that:public class  SQLConnector {    
     public static List<Trader> getListInfo() {     Syntax: "jdbc:mysql://ipaddress:portnumber/db_name"  
      Connection con =null;
      List<Trader> traderList=new ArrayList<Trader>();
      String username = "xxxxx"; 
   String password = "xxxxx";    
   //Query to Execute

Comment: getListInfo() only gets the rows once (the rows that exist at the time they're fetched) - how do you plan to fetch newly added rows?

Comment: Jamey, What is your recommendation about how to plan this. Currently sql connector is in a loop for 2 hrs execution and I intend to get rows every sec and if there is a new row, I want to assign new thread and start that thread. I tried to paste the whole code but unable to because of character limit. Would it be possible for me send the code to you? Its my first post on stackoverflow. Thank you for looking into my question. Appreciate it very much!